# Predict function works but forecast doesn't

Tags: r, regression, prediction, forecasting

```
Sample :-

Change  Name   Age
-5.20   BBB     58
-3.59   AAA     59
-3.53   CCC     129
-4.33   CCC     76
-3.23   CCC     117
-4.37   BBB     32
-3.95   DDD     76
-2.91   CCC     49

New  :-

Change   Name    Age
-3.53    CCC     127
-5.30    BBB     61
-3.10    CCC     88
-2.93    CCC     52
-4.75    BBB     35
-2.8     CCC     52
-3.5     CCC     132
-4.01    DDD     79

require(forecast)   
m<- lm(Change ~ Name+ Age, data=sample)
f<- forecast.lm(object = m,newdata = New)
p<- predict.lm(object = m,newdata = New)
```

The predict function works in this case but the forecast function gives an error. The error is

```
Error in if (nrow(origdata) != length(fcast$x)) tspx <- NULL : 
 argument is of length zero
```

I have done a lot of test to see that there are no NA or Null values in both sample data and new data used for forecasting. I want to use the forecast function because then I can use the accuracy and other such functions with the forecast object. Please help.

Comment: @coffeinjunky The function is from part of the `forecast` library. But I agree that without sample data and without any reproducible example it is virtually impossible to give a useful answer.

Comment: @coffeinjunky Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Jain, place a dput of sample in your question, please?

Comment: @hd1 I have added the data . Thanks

Comment: Using `forecast::forecast.lm` works fine for me. Can you provide us with the output of `sessionInfo()`? I suspect that you have another package loaded that has its own `forecast.lm` method.

Comment: @Jain, that's does not look like dput output to me

Comment: @hd1 That downvote is from you, but understand that I cannot post the entire data set . Thanks for your help

Comment: @coffeinjunky Changing the sample to someother name solves it. Now I see that sample is an base function and can still be used as a variable name. Its correctly works with the regression but throws an error while using forecast function. on the other side Predict function does not have any problem if one uses sample as a keyword.

Comment: @coffeinjunky Thanks, I will write it.

Comment: @Jain, I do not downvote, full stop